# Javascript map/reduce to find newest version of array items

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have an array of messages, and I'd like to reduce it to just contain the newest versions of those messages.

I've solved the problem with plain old JS using: forEach to put each message into dictionary keyed by `id`, over-writing previous versions, then convert dict to array via `Array.from(mathes.values)`

But, I'd like to learn more about modern ES JS - and suspect there is a clever map/reduce to solve my issue.

```
const messages = []
messages.push({id: 1, ver:1})
messages.push({id: 2, ver:1})
messages.push({id: 3, ver:1})
messages.push({id: 1, ver:2})
messages.push({id: 2, ver:2})
messages.push({id: 2, ver:3})

const newest = [] // some fancy map/reduce

console.log(newest)
// [{id: 1, ver:2},
// {id: 2, ver:3},
// {id: 3, ver:1}]
```

Can anybody give me hand with the map/reduce to perform the above?

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to map the objects into an array of *entries*, which get turned into an object with `Object.fromEntries`, thus keeping only the latest IDs:

```js
const arr = [
{id: 1, ver:1},
{id: 2, ver:1},
{id: 3, ver:1},
{id: 1, ver:2},
{id: 2, ver:2},
{id: 2, ver:3},
];

const dedup = Object.values(
  Object.fromEntries(
    arr.map(item => [item.id, item])
  )
);
console.log(dedup);
```

Comment: Solution is fine as long as the versions are in order. If they are not, it would need to be sorted.

Comment: Nicely presented, thanks.  The versions are in order, so I don't need to worry about that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple reduce that checks to see if the version is greater. After object is created, just grabs the values from it.

```js
const messages = []
messages.push({id: 1, ver:1})
messages.push({id: 2, ver:1})
messages.push({id: 3, ver:1})
messages.push({id: 1, ver:2})
messages.push({id: 2, ver:2})
messages.push({id: 2, ver:3})

const newest = Object.values(messages.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.id] || acc[item.id].ver < item.ver ) {
    acc[item.id] = item;
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(newest);
```